# Display image when player hits the wall

Tags: python, 2d, pygame, sprite, maze

I am just learning pygame and I have this so far. It is a maze (level not done yet :P) and when you get to the red block ("E") it opens a screen that says "You Win". I want to make it so when you hit the walls it displays a screen that says "You Lose" Whats the best way to go about this? Thanks!

```
import os
import random
import pygame

# Define colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
green    = (   0, 255,   0)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)

#Booleans
hasWon = False

#Classes
class Wall(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(32, 32, 16, 16)      

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)

    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):

        # Move the rect
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0: # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                    testing = True
                if dx < 0: # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                    testing = True
                if dy > 0: # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                    testing = True
                if dy < 0: # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
                    testing = True

#Initalize
pygame.init()
#Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
size=[688,352]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
#Name on top tab
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Set positions of graphics
background_position = [0, 0]

# Load and set up graphics.
win_screen = pygame.image.load("winscreen.jpg").convert()
lose_screen = pygame.image.load("losescreen.jpg").convert()

#Arrays/Lists
walls = [] # List to hold the walls

#Create Player
player = Player()

#Level
level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWW                                      WW",
"WW   WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
"W   WWWW       W                          W",
"W   W        WWWW                         W",
"W WWW  WWWW                               W",
"W   W     W W                             W",
"W   W     W   WWW W                       W",
"W   WWW WWW   W W                         W",
"W     W   W   W W                         W",
"WWW   W   WWWWW W                         W",
"WEW      WW                               W",
"W W   WWWW   WWW                          W",
"W     W    W   W                          W",
"W                                         W",
"W                                         W",
"W                                         W",
"W                                         W",
"W                                         W",
"W                                         W",
"WE    WWWW                                W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]

# Parse the level string above. W = wall, E = exit
x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
            Wall((x, y))
        if col == "E":
            end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 16, 16)
        x += 16        
    y += 16
    x = 0    
#DONT CHANGE
done = False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

#MAIN LOOP
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Quit                     


    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(white)

    #Changing Speed
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if hasWon == False:
        if hasLost == False:
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                player.move(-2, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                player.move(2, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                player.move(0, -2)
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                player.move(0, 2)    



    #Drawing
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 200, 0), player.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)
    for wall in walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, wall.rect)    

    #Win
    if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):
        screen.blit(win_screen, background_position)
        hasWon = True

    #FPS Lock
    clock.tick(60)

    #Update screen
    pygame.display.flip()

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how you could understand how to use `colliderect` without having the faintest idea about the existence of `collidelist`, which is documented right next to it…

Answer (score 1):

The [`collidelist`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) function does basically the same thing as the `colliderect` you're already using, except that it takes a list of rectangles to check instead of just one.

What you have is not a list of rectangles, but a list of `Wall` objects, each of which *has* a rectangle. But that's easy to fix:

```
wall_rects = [wall.rect for wall in walls]
```

So, now you just do this:

```
#Lose
if player.rect.collidelist(wall_rects):
    screen.blit(lose_screen, background_position)
    hasLost = True
```

Of course you also need to create a `lose_screen` to display, and set `hasLost = False` at the start.

---

As a side note, your code keeps running the main loop and allowing the user to move around even after he's won. And with this change, the same will be true even after he's lost. I'm guessing you actually want to do something different once either `hasWon` or `hasLost` is true, but it's up to you to decide what that something should be.